# Project c# cannot build after update MS RDLC Report designer

Tags: c#, rdlc

Yesterday, I've updated MS RDLC report designer extension in my VS 2007. But after that, my project (include rdlc report) cannot build and run even it has no error during building process. Other project don't use rdlc report can build successfully.

Comment: you mean VS2017?

Comment: Yes ofcouse. My project with rdlc report can run well before i updated report designer tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After try many way from internet but cannot solve the problem. I try to install visual 2015 with option sql data report component to support building rdlc report. Then I open my project and fix some compatible error in rdlc template file. And finally my project can run well.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds similar to the issue that was resolved with version 15.3 of the [Microsoft RDLC Report Designer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProBITools.MicrosoftRdlcReportDesignerforVisualStudio-18001) extension.